# Remove Tax from showing up in Cart page and Checkout

Tags: magento1.9.2.4, shipping-tax

Whenever I choose a Shipping method that isn't free in cart it shows the tax in the cart page: [Cart](https://hostr.co/file/MpA02l4AfX5R/Screenshoton2017-07-24at18.06.55.png)

And it isn't even correct because it should be 22 % (Italian VAT). 
How can I hide it?

This is what it looks like in Sales > Tax :
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2683080/b18d7effdd424a3025cb3d9a20f193c3

Answer (score 0):

In Calculation Settings > Shipping Prices, Set Shipping Prices to Exclude tax.